# Excel xy scatter chart: how do I add vertical lines from horizontal axis up to each data point?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-365

I would like to produce a chart that looks kind of like a bar graph, except the bars (thin lines would be fine, too) would be placed at their actual location respective to the axis. I am well aware bar graphs and xy scatter charts are completely different. It is the look of xy scatter chart I am trying to change.

It would be nice to be able to customize what it is that connects vertically from horizontal axis to each data point: whether it be a wide bar, an arrow, or a thin line. And also whether to show a dot at the data location or not would be nice to be able to specify.

So, what would this be even called, and how do I accomplish this? THANK YOU FOR HELP!!!

Chart on bottom is close to what I need:

[image: Chart]

Comment: Karl, I just got to work to verify this. Yep, it solves my need, using this workaround of error bars. The only slightly confusing part is about "select vertical bars". Here is a slightly expanded info:
When horizontal bars appear, in the right pane under Chart Options, select "Series ... Y error bars", then under Error Bar Options tab, do the adjustments as described. THEN the horizontal error bars can be deleted...

I don't see an obvious way to tag this as "solved". How do I do that for your Answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to admit that this is a very interesting idea. Fortunately, an easy workaround to achieve exactly this exists and can look like the following (I used only the information in columns A and B of your data respectively; but of course you can expand it as needed).

First, select your data and insert an `xy scatter` (similar to your first chart). Select the data points (blue dots in my case) and press the `+` sign next to the chart to add `chart elements` and insert `error bars - percentage`. You can select the horizontal error bars and delete them.  Then select the `vertical error bars`, `right-click` and choose `Format Error Bars...`. Here you need to make the following settings:

`Direction`: Minus

`End Style`: No Cap

`Percentage`: 100%

And finally, you can format the dots and error bars in terms of color, shape, size, etc. according to your needs. On a side note, this approach is very flexible. I used the same xy values. However, theoretically you could change this and add additional data, such as the average of your data. Of course, you could also use both horizontal and vertical error bars to connect them to the x and y axes, respectively.

The final chart looks as follows:

[image: Chart with vertical lines to horizontal axis]